# Error Print : " actual and formal argument lists differ in length java"

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have a problem with `println`. I tried to print "method" from one class to another, but get this error:

> actual and formal argument lists differ in length java

This is the method:

```
public double dayInWeek(int day, int month, int year) {
    int Day;
    int M;
    int Y = _year%100;
    int C = _year/100;
    int D = _day;
    if (_month == 1) { 
        M = 13;
    } else if ( _month == 2) {
        M = 14;
    } else {
        M = _month;
    }
    return Day = (D + (26*(M+1))/10 + Y + Y/4 + C/4 - 2*C) % 7;
}
```

This is in the main:

```
System.out.println(d5+" occurs on : "+d5.dayInWeek());
```

Why do I get this error?

Comment: `dayInWeek` takes arguments! Read the error...

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell what Type d5 is but if dayInWeek() is a method in the class of d5 then you should do the following:

```
public double dayInWeek(int day , int month ,int year){
    return Day = (this.day + (26*(this.month+1))/10 + tis.year + this.year/4 + this.century/4 - 2*this.century) % 7;
}
```

or something like that.

On the other hand if dayInWeek() is a local method or a static method do something like this:

```
System.out.println(d5+" occurs on : "+dayInWeek(d5.day, d5.month, d5.year));
```

or likewise. Like the error said, the list of arguments that dayInWeek got (none of them) was different from the list of arguments dayInWeek wants (3 ints)